# How to auto trim with Imagemagick while retaining a small border?

Tags: imagemagick, crop

I have a large number of files that have a picture of a coin on a black felt background.  Using ImageMagick I can fairly straightforwardly auto-trim these images using -trim and -fuzz.

The edge detection is working well, what I would like to find is a parameter that would allow me to say "find the edge but then back up 10 pixels", that is, retain a 10 pixel perimeter around the coin instead of cropping right against it.  I do not wish to add a new border as with the -splice command but rather retain that spacing from the original image.

So far I haven't found a way to do it, the closest I've come up with is to run it in -trim info:- mode, capture the output and recalculate the crop using a manual crop but I'd really prefer a one step process.

I am using ImageMagick under Windows 10 and while I have installed the bash extensions I have not tested any scripts under it, so a solution that purely uses the Imagemagick command line would be preferred.

Answer (score 4):

For lack of an elegant solution I went with a working one and wrote a crude bash script that seems to do the job nicely.  This leaves a 25px offset all around the coin using the original graphic to provide the background.  I'll eventually parameterize that and clean this up but it is today's working script.

```
for f in *.jpg; do
    trimbox=$(convert $f -fuzz 25% -format "%@" info:)
    orig=$trimbox
    first=${trimbox%x*}
    trimbox=${trimbox#*x}
    second=${trimbox%%+*}
    trimbox=${trimbox#*+}
    third=${trimbox%+*}
    fourth=${trimbox#*+}
    #echo "trimbox: $orig first: $first second: $second third: $third fourth:$fourth"
    ((first+=50))
    ((second+=50))
    ((third-=25))
    ((fourth-=25))
    trimbox=$first"x"$second"+"$third"+"$fourth
    convert "$f" -crop "$trimbox" +repage "trimmed-$f"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `-border` and `-bordercolor` for this - e.g. for a transparent border, you might want:

```
for f in *.jpg; do
  convert -fuzz 25% -trim -border 25 -bordercolor none +repage $f trimmed-$f
done
```

See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#border

Comment: should be `-bordercolor none -border 25` for a transparent border or `-bordercolor white -border 25` for a white border